# Jquery Animation : how to make text appear when a element has changed color or styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Umm guys i got stuck in Jquery when i was fiddling along with some animation The thing was i wanted to make a textbox appear and show the text when a button is highlighted like a gallery ummm ..... . Anyway i made halfthrough but the text is not displaying . so any help...

P.s the idea was to have a  button/circle glow and a text to appear below it
like when one button/circle glows an empty space below shows the text associated with it.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

            function slide() 
            {//slide start

                $(".textHold").hide()
                .delay(1000)
                .queue(
                    function()
                    {//queue function start
                        $(".red").css(
                        {//css start
                            "background-color":"#000"
                        }//css end
                                    );//css ();
                    $(this).dequeue();
                    }//queue function/\
                    );//queue();

                $(".textHold").fadeIn(500);
                $(".textr").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(5000).delay(500);
                $(".textHold").fadeOut(500).delay(500);
                $(".textHold")
                .queue(
                    function ()
                    {
                        $(".red").css({"background-color":"#f00"});
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    }
                )
                .delay(500)
                .queue(
                    function()
                    {
                        $(".blue").css({"background-           color":"#000"});
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    }
                )

                .fadeIn(500);$(".text").fadeIn(500).delay(500).fadeOut(500).delay(500);
            $(".textHold").fadeOut(500).delay(500);
                $(".textHold").queue(
                    function()
                        {
                        $(".blue").css({"background-color":"#00f"});
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    }
                    );
                }//slide() /\
setInterval(function(){slide();},500);

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="textHold">
    <span class="text">Hello blue</span>
    <span class="textr">Hello Red</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the code to change the style for the button is under your control (not a third party code). In this case, you can trigger a JQuery custom event when button changes color. There would be a listener to this event which will according make the text appear.

See: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/